# default value for timestamp in mysql

Tags: mysql

mysql version is 5.7.20

```
create table test (
  start_day                     timestamp,
  create_time                   timestamp NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  
  update_time                   timestamp NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

this sql can execute well.

```
create table test (
  start_day                     timestamp,
  create_time                   timestamp,  
  update_time                   timestamp
);
```

Otherwise, this sql shows 1067 - Invalid default value for 'create_time'.
In first sql, I found that the default value for start_day is CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, and it will update automatically.
Can someone explain what is the default value in the second sql and what is the difference between the two sql.

Comment: The code is correct itself. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e348b91f27b291ea5d689360bb114a0f).  Show `SELECT @@sql_mode` output.

Comment: Why would create_time have an UPDATE?

Comment: @Akina the first sql is correct, why the second is wrong

Comment: @Strawberry just for test

Comment: Investigate [explicit_defaults_for_timestamp system variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp) description.